# My circles are not matching up with my planets orbits

Tags: python, matplotlib

My planets orbits are not matching up with my circular paths im plotting of the orbits, I have matched in my for loop the distance for every planet with the distance they are from the center.(image is attached)
    from pylab import * 
    from matplotlib.animation import *
Here is where I am defining the circes I will plot to show the paths of the orbits at the "def circle..."

```
def circle(x0,y0,R,N) :
    ''' create circle, given center x0,y0, input radius R,
        and number of points N, then 
        output arrays of x and y coordinates '''

    theta = linspace(0.0,2.0*pi,N)
    x = R * cos(theta) + x0
    y = R * sin(theta) + y0
    return x,y  


a= array([.39,.72,1,1.52,5.20,9.54,19.2,30.1]) #astronomical units of #the planets in order of the planets(i.e mercury, venus, earth,mars...) 
period = a**(3.0/2.0)
```

I am taking the distane of the planets and inputting them in array, to be able to use a for loop to graph the circles.

```
#distance of the planets 
d= array([390,790,980, 1520,5200,9540,19200,30100])#same order of the #planets as well 

#attributes of the sun
x0 =0 
y0 = 0
r_s=70*1.2#actual earth radius is 695e6 

#radius of the planets 
r_Ear = 63.781#e in m {for all the planets}
r_Merc= 24
r_Ven = 60 
r_Mars= 33.9
r_Jup = 700
r_Sat = 582 
r_Ura = 253
r_Nep = 246
```

the actual distance of the planets

```
#Distance of the planets
d_Ear = 1000#152
d_Merc= 390#70
d_Ven = 790#109
d_Mars= 1520#249
d_Jup = 5200#816
d_Sat = 9540#1514
d_Ura = 19200#3003
d_Nep = 30100#4545

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(-1e4-5000, 1e4+5000), ylim=(-1e4-5000, 1e4+5000), aspect=True)
```

This is where I am looping over, to plot 8 circles. Theres a link here to see the plot I have generated.

```
for i in range(8) :
    x, y = circle(0.0,0.0,d[i],10000) # orbit
    plot(x,y,':k')
[enter image description here][1]
```

The rest are the patches of the planets and the FuncAnimation.

```
Sun = plt.Circle((x0, y0), radius=r_s, ec='yellow', fc='yellow', lw=3)
Mercury = plt.Circle((0, 0), radius=r_Merc, ec='brown', fc='brown', lw=3)
Venus = plt.Circle((0, 0), radius=r_Ven, ec='brown', fc='brown', lw=3)
Earth = plt.Circle((0, 0), radius=r_Ear, ec='black', fc='black', lw=3)
Mars = plt.Circle((0, 0), radius=r_Mars, ec='brown', fc='brown', lw=3)
Jupiter = plt.Circle((0, 0), radius=r_Jup, ec='green', fc='green', lw=3)
Saturn = plt.Circle((0, 0), radius=r_Sat, ec='green', fc='green', lw=3)
Uranus = plt.Circle((0, 0), radius=r_Ura, ec='green', fc='green', lw=3)
Neptune = plt.Circle((0, 0), radius=r_Nep, ec='green', fc='green', lw=3)

ax.add_patch(Sun)

def init():

    ax.add_patch(Earth)
    ax.add_patch(Mercury)
    ax.add_patch(Venus) 
    ax.add_patch(Mars) 
    ax.add_patch(Jupiter)
    ax.add_patch(Saturn)
    ax.add_patch(Uranus)
    ax.add_patch(Neptune)

    return Mercury, Venus,Earth,Mars,Jupiter,Saturn,Uranus,Neptune,
def animate(i):


    theta = radians(i)
    mx = d_Merc*np.cos(theta/period[0]) - d_Merc*np.sin(theta/period[0])
    my = d_Merc*np.sin(theta/period[0]) + d_Merc*np.cos(theta/period[0])

    vx = d_Ven *np.cos(theta/period[1]) - d_Ven*np.sin(theta/period[1]) 
    vy = d_Ven *np.cos(theta/period[1]) + d_Ven*np.sin(theta/period[1])

    ex = d_Ear*np.cos(theta/period[2]) - d_Ear*np.sin(theta/period[2])
    ey = d_Ear*np.sin(theta/period[2]) + d_Ear*np.cos(theta/period[2])

    Mx = d_Mars*np.cos(theta/period[3]) - d_Mars*np.sin(theta/period[3])
    My = d_Mars*np.sin(theta/period[3]) + d_Mars*np.cos(theta/period[3])

    Jx = d_Jup*np.cos(theta/period[4]) - d_Jup*np.sin(theta/period[4])
    Jy = d_Jup*np.sin(theta/period[4]) + d_Jup*np.cos(theta/period[4])

    Sx = d_Sat*np.cos(theta/period[5]) - d_Sat*np.sin(theta/period[5])
    Sy = d_Sat*np.sin(theta/period[5]) + d_Sat*np.cos(theta/period[5])

    Ux = d_Ura*np.cos(theta/period[6]) - d_Ura*np.sin(theta/period[6])
    Uy = d_Ura*np.sin(theta/period[6]) + d_Ura*np.cos(theta/period[6])

    Nx = d_Nep*np.cos(theta/period[7]) - d_Nep*np.sin(theta/period[7])
    Ny = d_Nep*np.sin(theta/period[7]) + d_Nep*np.cos(theta/period[7])

    Mercury.center = (mx, my)
    Mercury._angle = i
    Venus.center = (vx, vy)
    Venus._angle = i
    Earth.center = (ex, ey)
    Earth._angle = i
    Mars.center  = (Mx, My)
    Mars.angle =i 
    Jupiter.center = (Jx, Jy)
    Jupiter._angle = i
    Saturn.center = (Sx, Sy)
    Saturn._angle = i
    Uranus.center = (Ux, Uy)
    Uranus.angle = i 
    Neptune.center = (Nx, Ny)
    Neptune._angle = i





    return  Mercury, Venus, Earth, Mars, Jupiter, Saturn, Uranus,          Neptune,

anim = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init, frames=1080, 
                               interval=25, blit=True)


plt.show()
```

Comment: If this is not intended as a programming exercise but part of a larger project, I would also have a look at orbit plotting in [pykep](https://esa.github.io/pykep/documentation/orbitplots.html).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not following your math on this:

```
mx = d_Merc*np.cos(theta/period[0]) - d_Merc*np.sin(theta/period[0])
my = d_Merc*np.sin(theta/period[0]) + d_Merc*np.cos(theta/period[0])
```

You'll be more correct if you change that to this:

```
mx = d_Merc*np.cos(theta/period[0])
my = d_Merc*np.sin(theta/period[0])
```

And even more correct if you take the size of the planet into account

```
mx = (d_Merc+(r_Merc/2))*np.cos(theta/period[0])
my = (d_Merc+(r_Merc/2))*np.sin(theta/period[0])
```

That will fix your basic issue I think.

Beyond that:

- d_Ear differs from Earth's value in the `d` array. 980 vs. 1000.
- `vy = d_Ven *np.cos(theta/period[1])` is not correct. That needs
  to be `vy = d_Ven *np.sin(theta/period[1])`
- As far as the code goes, you may consider using a few dictionaries to
  avoid repetition like with your `d` array.

Comment: **exactly** (+1) the OP used rotation formula which would work if it would be used by `(r,0)` or `(0,r)` instead of `(r,r)` which makes the position with 45 deg phase offset and `sqrt(2)` bigger radius than it should.